# Where do you clone Python module git repositories?

Tags: python, git, github, module, repository

I'm interested in contributing to a GitHub Python module repo, but I'm not entirely sure where to clone it. This is a simple module, just an `__init__.py` and some `.py` files. No other files need to be installed or changed outside of the module's folder.

I would like to be able to clone the repository directly in my site-packages folder. When I want to use the library as is, I would switch to the master branch. If I want to develop a new feature, can branch off of devel. If I want to try out a new feature someone else implemented, I can switch to that particular branch. I can even keep it in the development branch, to get the latest, albeit possibly unstable, features. All this without having to change the `import` statement to point to a different location in any of my scripts. This option, even though is seems to do all the things I want it to do, seems a bit wrong for some reason. Also, I'm not sure what this would do to pip when calling `python -m pip list --outdated`. I have a feeling it won't know what the current version is.

Another option would be to clone it to some other folder and keep only the pip-installed variant in the site-packages folder. That way I would have a properly installed library in site-packages and I could try out new features by creating a script inside the repo folder. This doesn't seem nearly as flexible as the option above, but it doesn't mess with the site-packages folder.

Which is the best way to go about this? How do you clone repositories when you both want to work on them and use them with the latest features?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more a question about packaging and open source than Python itself, but I'll try to help you out.

- If you want to host your package on Pip, you should go [here](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html), and there you'll see how to upload and tag appropriately your package for usage.
- If you want to add some functionality to some open source library, what you could do is to try to [submit a Pull Request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) to that library, so everybody can use it. Rules for PR are specific for each project, you you should ask the maintainer.
- If your modification doesn't get merged into master, but you still want to use it without changing `import` statements, you could *fork* that repo, and publish your own modifications on, for instance, Github.

  In that case, you could install you modifications like this:

  ```
  pip install git+https://github.com/username/amazing-project.git
  ```

  So in that way, your library will come from your own repo.

If you're going for the third option, I strongly recommend you using `virtualenv`, where you can create different virtual environments with different packages, dependencies and so on, without messing up with your Python installation. A nice guide is available [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that's not what I wanted to know. I know how to contribute to a project, I just don't know where I should clone the repository: in site-packages or somewhere else.

Comment: In that case, I think the best you could do to test the development of your package is to use virtual environments, in, this way you can switch back and forth between versions.

Comment: That is a good point, but I can do that with git by switching to the release branch. But, yes, if there is no release branch or it differs from the actual release, then virtual environments would be a good solution.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to deal with this where the python package is in a sub-directory of the git repo root?  An example is `pandas`.  I would like to `git clone` the `pandas` repo into the `site-packages` directory but then the actual python package would then be in `site-packages/pandas/pandas` which means that `import` statements don't work as normal.